# Save images to folder using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have a few images which are extracted from other images using [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

I've tried to save these images into a folder, but only last image is being saved to folder with my code.

```
 Image.ToBitmap().save("filename",imageformat.png)
```

How I could save all images in one folder?

Comment: looks like you overwriting the file. you should be using different file names each time.....

Comment: But i have assigned extractedtables to image .dont know how mang tables in one image .so how to iterate them one by one and  give different file names

Comment: Some grammar issues in question were fixed to be more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is made for WinForms, but same principles should apply to to all the UI frameworks.**

If you want to be able to choose the folder in run time, then you can use this code:

```
 void Unique(Image input)
    {
        string fileName = "filename.jpg";
        string newFileName = null;

        //Crates the dialog window
        var dirDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (dirDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            newFileName = dirDialog.SelectedPath + fileName;

            for (int i = 1; true; i++)
            {


                //this is so that you can alter the name and keep the file format 
                newFileName = fileName.Split('.')[0] + "_{i}" + fileName.Split('.')[1];

                if (!File.Exists(newFileName))
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            //save the file
            new Bitmap(input).Save(newFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        //deletes the dialog window from memory
        dirDialog.Dispose();
    }
```

But **keep in mind** that this code will ask you for the folder every time that you are going to save the file. So if you are going to save multiple files at once, I would advise you to save the `dirDialog.SelectedPath` in some `string` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing something like this. I have taken the name of the file and I'm asking if the file already exist and if it does, it adds number to the file name and it does in such a way that it keeps the file format. But if you don't want to save it with the file format you can do it without the `fileName.Split();` just by adding the number behind the file name `newFileName = fileName+$"_{i}";`.

```
//if you want you can use this method or just copy the code you need
void Unique(Image input)
{
    string fileName = "filename.jpg";
    string newFilename = null;
    for(int i = 1; true; i++)

        //this is so that you can alter the name and keep the file format 
        newFileName = filename.Split('.')[0]+"_{i}"+filename.Split('.')[1];

        if(!File.Exist(newFileName))
        {   
            break;
        }
    }
    return Image.ToBitmap().Save(newFileName,ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: How to add folder here to save the images into folder

Comment: @SrinuReddy And do you want for the folder to be always the same, or do you want to be able to choose the folder in run time?